# Citations for the proof of universality of graph classes

Tags: graph-theory, first-order-logic, symmetric-groups, universal-algebra, universal-property

In [Automorphisms of graphs](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~leonard/designtheory.org/library/preprints/auts.pdf), Peter J. Cameron mentioned following classes of graphs which are universal structures.

1. graphs of valency k for any fixed k > 2;
2. bipartite graphs;
3. strongly regular graphs;
4. Hamiltonian graphs;
5. k-connected graphs, for k > 0;
6. k-chromatic graphs, for k > 1;
7. switching classes of graphs;
8. lattices;
9. projective planes (possibly infinite);
10. Steiner triple systems;
11. symmetric designs (BIBDs).

Cameron mentioned that the results are due to people like Frucht,
Sabidussi, Mendelsohn, Babai, Kantor, and others.

**My question:**

Could anyone please point me to the individual reference for all or some of the classes?

Comment: What is "universal structure"? Is that some category theory thing? What does it mean in human language for a class of graphs to be a "universal structure"?

Comment: In this context it means that any abelian group can be realised as the automorphism group of some graph from the class - that is, the group of symmetries of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 27 of Babai's "Handbook of Combinatorics" discusses automorphism groups, and in particular section 4 covers the universality problem.  He does provide a number of references.  You can access the chapter [here](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/handbook/handbookchapter27.pdf).

Trivalent graphs: R. Frucht, "Graphs of degree 3 with given abstract group", Canad. J. Math. 1 (1949), 365-378.

Regular graphs (valency $k \ge 4$), $k$-connected graphs, Hamiltonian graphs: G. Sabidussi, "Graphs with given automorphism group and given graph theoretical
properties", Canad. J. Math. 9 (1957), 515–525. [ [paper](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=QYD6bxzQ2XEC&oi=fnd&pg=PA515&dq=Graphs%20of%20degree%203%20with%20given%20abstract%20group&ots=VZl-kbLqVD&sig=an0WWe-8HqRcp8a8ER7t-S9kfuI&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Graphs%20of%20degree%203%20with%20given%20abstract%20group&f=false) ]

Strongly regular graphs: E. Mendelsohn, "Every (finite) group is the group of automorphisms of a (finite) strongly regular graph", Ars. Combinatoria 6 (1978), 75–86.

Lattices: G. Birkhoff, "Sobre los grupos de automorfismos", Revista Uni´on Math. Argentina 11 (1945), 155–157.  [ [paper (in Spanish (I presume))](http://inmabb.criba.edu.ar/revuma/pdf/v11n4/p155-157.pdf) ]

Steiner triple systems:  E. Mendelsohn, "On the groups of automorphisms of Steiner triple and quadruple systems", J. Comb. Theory A 25 (1978), 97–104. [ [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316578900729) ]

Those were the references I extracted from that section.  Babai does refer to a survey of his own for proofs and further references:

L. Babai, "On the abstract group of automorphisms", In Combinatorics, volume 52
of London Math. Soc. Lecture Notes, pages 1–40. Cambridge Univ. Press, London,
1981.  [ [preview](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=sk6-MknG-xEC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=On%20the%20abstract%20group%20of%20automorphisms.&ots=KkIyRcCUx0&sig=-tuV8z1AumEg2HaVBHnsc_ab8M4&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=On%20the%20abstract%20group%20of%20automorphisms.&f=false) ]

Comment: Hi, Shagnik. Welcome to MSE.

Comment: @i707107: Thanks, and hi back at you!  (Did I make a rookie mistake somewhere?)

Comment: No, just saying hi. You probably know me.

Comment: @i707107: well, that's a relief :)  I'm guessing you may not want me to name you here, but it's always nice to meet an office mate again!  How's everything going?

Comment: Going okay! Thank you for asking, how about you?

Comment: @i707107: Can't complain, being kept busy at the moment, and StackExchange is a pleasant distraction from my less-enjoyable tasks.